# cat rejects sibling

Tags: behavior

our cats are 2 1/2 yrs old, male and female. male recently had an event that looked like it could have been a seizure. he bolted upright from sleeping on his favorite couch pillow, ran around the living room and directly down the long hall to his favorite bedroom that has been the "safe" room for both kitties. in mid run he was joined by his sister who may have joined in as if it were play. but, how are we to know that? since then he has refused to leave that room, has been perfectly contented to be there, is perfectly happy and healthy seeming, but rejects her, hisses at her and chases her from the room, while she demurs to his aggression. it's been a month. we've tried carrying him around the house to desensitize him, but all he does is cower in our arms and shiver and quake.
help!

Comment: If you haven't already, I would suggest checking with your vet for medical causes, since you describe an event like a seizure, something neurological maybe. In any case, something traumatic happened and it sounds like he somehow associated this with his sister. I would not force anything at this point, the best approach tends to be to work with the pets according to their own pace.

Comment: our feeling as well. it's been a month and this formally social,  loving affectionate member of the family hides. heartbreaking